# PDO & MYSQL listing results with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

still quite nooby at PHP and I am just wondering how I can make this possible.

I am trying to list all of the MySQL table data using a PDO query.

Basically I want to show the two columns I have in the table in a list and loop the html for each row.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container-div">
  <h3 class="make"></h3>
  <div class="side-cont">
    <h4 class="model"></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

My table has two columns like the following:

```
Make, Model
```

I am connecting to the database with the following PHP:

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname","user","password");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not connect to the database.";
    exit;
}

try {
    $results = $db->query("SELECT Make, Model FROM import ORDER BY Make ASC");
    echo "Successful.";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error.";
    exit;
}

?>
```

As you can see this code is establishing a connection with the database.

Now I have been able to print the data onto the page using:

```
$results = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach( $results as $result ){
        echo $result['Make'];
    }
```

I am just unsure how I can print this data within the HTML I have supplied.

Any examples would be great thanks, this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<div class="container-div">
  <h3 class="make">Make Column</h3>
  <div class="side-cont">
    <h4 class="model">Model Column</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then loop the HTML so it shows the second row etc...

```
<div class="container-div">
  <h3 class="make">Make Column Row Two</h3>
  <div class="side-cont">
    <h4 class="model">Model Column Row Two</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to loop through your resultset, it's always easier to do it with `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`. you can use it in a `while` loop just like this:

```
while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo '
        <div class="container-div">
          <h3 class="make">'.$row["Make"].'</h3>
          <div class="side-cont">
            <h4 class="model">'.$row["Model"].'</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
    ';
}
```

`fetch` returns one row of your resultset on each call (EDIT: and then sets the cursor to the next row) while `fetchAll` returns the whole resultset at once.

Comment: How is this looping the results without a foreach loop?

Works great though

Comment: cause, like i mentioned, `fetch` only retrieves one row of the resultset each time you call it and then sets the cursor to the next row. if it's at the end of the resultset (after returning the last row of it), `fetch` returns `false` which automatically ends the `while` loop.